# How to show day name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2017

I have a query on the SQL server

I want to display as below:

```
CDATE      | CDAY
2019-04-01 | Monday
2019-04-02 | Tuesday
...        | ......
2019-04-30 | Tuesday
```

But I found error as below:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Please if someone can help

```
DECLARE @V_DATE DATE = GETDATE()

;WITH CTE_DATE AS (
        SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@V_DATE)-1),@V_DATE) CDATE,
        DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@V_DATE)-1),@V_DATE))) CDAY
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE),
        DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dw,1,CDAY)))
        FROM    CTE_DATE
        WHERE   DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE) <= DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))

    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE_DATE
```

Comment: Take smaller steps. Start with a basic, single SELECT.

Comment: Use the cte to generate dates only, fix the day name in the main query.

Comment: I think you may be able to remove the part where you convert the date to varchar also, depending on what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dw, 1, CDAY))
```

I think you intend:

```
DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dw, 1, CDATE))
```

I would write the CTE as:

```
WITH CTE_DATE AS (
        SELECT  DATEADD(day ,-(DAY(@V_DATE)-1),@V_DATE) as CDATE, 
                DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, -(DAY(@V_DATE) - 1), @V_DATE)) as CDAY
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(day, 1, CDATE),
                DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dw, 1, CDATE))
        FROM    CTE_DATE
        WHERE   DATEADD(day, 1, CDATE) <= DATEADD(day, -(DAY(DATEADD(month, 1, CDATE))), DATEADD(month, 1, CDATE))

    )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE_DATE;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce5023ef4534f404f182db61338fe9a7) is a db<>fiddle.

You don't describe what you want the code the code to do.  It has unnecessary conversions to string and might be needlessly complicated for what you want to do.

Comment: baik terima kasih. ini sangat membantu

Answer (score 3):

You can shortly use  [`datename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function( *used since v.2008* )

```
  select datename( weekday, getdate() ) as day

  day
  ------
  Friday  -- > "for today(2019-04-26)"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cbea6aedecf3bae9419609baa3bc8fff)</kbd>

or as in your case :

```
with t(cdate) as
(
 select '2019-04-01' union all
 select '2019-04-02' union all
 select '2019-04-30'    
)    
select cdate, datename( weekday, cdate  ) as cday
  from t;

+----------+-------+
| cdate    | cday  |
+----------+-------+
|2019-04-01|Monday |
|2019-04-02|Tuesday|
|2019-04-30|Tuesday|
+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to convert to varchar in order to get weekday.

```
 UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE),
        DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dw,1,CDAY))) -- No need to convert to varchar in order to get weekday.
        FROM    CTE_DATE
        WHERE   DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE) <= DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))
```

you can directly get it using datename function.

```
  DECLARE @V_DATE DATE = GETDATE()

    ;WITH CTE_DATE AS (
            SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@V_DATE)-1),@V_DATE) CDATE,
                    DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@V_DATE)-1),@V_DATE))) CDAY
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE),
                    DATENAME(dw,  DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE)) -- modified 
            FROM    CTE_DATE
            WHERE   DATEADD(dd,1,CDATE) <= DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,CDATE))

        )
        SELECT * FROM CTE_DATE
```

Comment: Care to spend 30 seconds explaining what you have done?

Comment: This looks very similar, it would help readers if you explained the changes you applied to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No need to fix the day names inside the CTE, use it only to generate the dates.

```
DECLARE @V_DATE DATE = GETDATE()

WITH CTE_DATE AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(day ,-(DAY(@V_DATE)-1),@V_DATE) as CDATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(day, 1, CDATE)
    FROM    CTE_DATE
    WHERE   DATEADD(day, 1, CDATE) <= DATEADD(day, -(DAY(DATEADD(month, 1, CDATE))), DATEADD(month, 1, CDATE))
)
SELECT CDATE, DATENAME(dw, CDATE) FROM CTE_DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to `CONVERT` dates. Use the [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. And use `EOMONTH` function:

```
DECLARE @V_DATE DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1));
WITH CTE_DATE AS (
    SELECT @V_DATE CDATE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, CDATE)
    FROM   CTE_DATE
    WHERE  DATEADD(dd, 1, CDATE) <= EOMONTH(@V_DATE)
)
SELECT CDATE, FORMAT(CDATE, 'dddd') AS CDAY, FORMAT(CDATE, 'ddd') AS CDAYSHORT
FROM CTE_DATE
```